# jointly normal with constant

Tags: probability

I am trying to calculate the mean for $Z = a_1 X_1 + a_2 X_2$. As a first step, I want to find the pdf for $(a_1 X_1, a_2 X_2)$ (I plan to convolve).

$X_1$ and $X_2$ are jointly normal. How can I do this? (specifically, how does the pdf of $(X_1, X_2)$ relate to that of $(a_1 X_1, a_2 X_2)$?

Answer (score 2):

If $X_1,X_2$ are jointly normal then $a_1X_1,a_2X_2$ are also jointly normal. So all you need is the mean vector and variance-covariance matrix of $(a_1X_1,a_2X_2)$. The mean vector is $(a_1EX_1, a_2EX_2)$. The variances are $a_1^{2}Var (X_1)$ and $a_2^{2}Var (X_2)$ and the covariance is $a_1a_2Cov (X_1,X_2)$.